# Why is if statement not working

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm new to programming and can't work this out and have looked everywhere i can think for an answer. The if statement in `function1` `if (m != 0 || 1)` doesn't seem to be read when `cin >> 1` is passed from `function2`. Here is my code, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

void function1(int i);

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    int i;

    function1(i);

return 0;
}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>

void function2();

void function1(int i) {
    using namespace std;
    if (i != 0 || 1 ) /* not working when the variable 'i' is passed from function2 */ {     
    cout << endl << "i != 0 || 1" << endl;
    function2();
    }
    else if (i == 0 || 1) {
        if (i == 0) {
            cout << endl << "m == 0" << endl;
        }
        else if (i == 1) {
            cout << endl << "m == 1" << endl;
        }
    }
}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>

void function1(int i);

void function2() {
    using namespace std;

    int i;

    cout << endl << "type 0 or 1" << endl;
    cin >> i;    /* type 1 or 0 in here */
    function1(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although user154248's answer is (in parts at least) correct, you might be interested in why...

The reason is that `operator!=` has higher precedence (i. e. is evaluated before) `operator||`. So your if clause is equivalent to `if((i != 0) || 1)`.

Additionally, any value unequal to 0 (null/zero) is evaluated to `true`, if used in an expresstion expecting a boolean parameter, so you get `if((i != 0) || true)`. And now, what ever `i != 0` evaluates to, the overall expression `x || true` will result in `true`.

Finally – we are back at user154248's answer...

However, there is a problem left: `i != 0 || i != 1` will also always evaluate to true: If i equals 0, `i != 1` evaluates to true, if i equals 1, `i != 0` does so...

What you actually need is `i != 0 && i != 1`.

Comment: Thanks, I usually forget to to the explaining part :)

Comment: Yes, that does work. I will be looking into your explanation to gain a more thorough understanding of it. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this:

```
if (i != 0 || 1 )
```

To this:

```
if (i != 0 || i != 1 )
```

Comment: No problem. I feel like this code can be trimmed down a lot though. I see you establishing `function1()` with an `int` parameter, but you don't seem to pass anything into it. The function won't be called if you don't explicitly do so from outside with an `int` parameter.

Comment: See my edit, I think you're trying to do something like this:

Comment: The code you pasted in with your edit is no valid c++. Actually, I don't get myself what you try to explain with it...

Comment: @Aconcagua you're right. That's what I get for switching languages three times already today.