# Why is my code returning only one function?

Tags: c, function

I am new to Programming (starting with C), and tried to practice functions by building a calculator. But it only ever returns me the same function even though its If-Statement is not being called. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int result;
int multiplication(int num1, int num2){

    result = num1 * num2;
    return result;
};

int addition(int num1, int num2){

    result = num1 + num2;
    return result;
};

int substraction(int num1, int num2){

    result = num1 - num2;
    return result;
};

int main(){
    int num1;
    int num2;
    char Math;

    printf("Do you want to do a Multiplication or an Addition, or a Substraction: ");
    scanf("%c", &Math);
    printf("Now give me a Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Now give me another Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num2);

    if(Math = 'M' || 'm'){
        printf("Your Mulitplication came out to %d", multiplication(num1,num2));
}
    else if(Math = 'A' || 'a'){
        printf("Your Addition came out to %d", addition(num1, num2));
}
    else if(Math = 'S' || 's'){
        printf("Your Substraction came out to %d", substraction(num1, num2));
}
    else{
        printf("Your Input was wrong");
};

return 0;



}
```

I would really appreciate every bit of advice i can get!

Comment: A few things I spotted.
1) "=" is an assignment operator. You want to use "==" in the if statement.  2) to compare if Var is 'X' or 'Y' you need to do "Var== 'X' || Var == 'Y'

Comment: these are very common mistakes for beginners to make, and come up here frequently - eg. : [If statements not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289635/if-statements-not-working), [Why is if statement not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554633/why-is-if-statement-not-working)

Comment: You should always enable warnings in your compiler. For GCC you canuse -Wall -Wextra. This might show you some warnings "assignment in condition" or similar. And please always take care about all warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This here

```
if(Math = 'M' || 'm')
```

Needs to be changed to

```
if((Math == 'M') || (Math == 'm'))
```

Because as it is, `'M' || 'm'` just turns into `1`, which is then assigned to `Math`, and that result is returned, which means the `if` is taken. With this change, you're actually comparing `Math` to `'M'`, and if it's not equal, to `'m'`.

Likewise for `else if(Math = 'A' || 'a')` and so on.

Comment: The second 'M' should be small 'm', but it's pretty clear what you meant.

Comment: @visibleman thanks for pointing this out. I just noticed I made this mistake twice - once in the code and once in the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**note**  (=) is diffrent from (==)

= is assignment operator it assigns the value in your code you are assigning the value 'M' to Math and logical operators return either 0 or 1.
in this case, it returns 1 
since 1 is returned control flows inside if 
and the result of the multiplication is obtained as output